# JavaScript click event does not work on mobile touchscreen

Tags: javascript, click, event-listener, touchscreen

i have problem with tiggering click event on mobile phone touchscreen. My button HTML looks like this:

```
<button id="size-selection-button" type="button" class="table-button border-radius-closed">
    <div class="button-text">
        Plotas<span><i class="fas fa-chevron-down table-arrow"></i></span>
    </div>
</button>
```

I am using JS 'click' event listener to trigger a function. It works fine on PC browser, it works fine when i select mobile device from Devtools but it does not work on my mobile phone (iphone) it just reacts as if i would hover on the button. I tried "touchstart" event, changed z-index, it does not change anything. I have few other buttons in same website with click event listener and they work fine with touchscreen. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Why would you have a div in a button?

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/L5z8b16e/show Safari and Chrome iPhone 11pro iOS 14.4